# Show that excision fails for the following pair $(X,A,U)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X=S^2$ ,$A={(x,y,0)\in S^2: x^2+y^2=1:x\geq 0)}$ and $U=(1,0,0)$ so $\bar{U}$ is contained in $A$ but we need to show that the inclusion $j:(X-U,A-U)\to (X,A)$ does not induce isomorphism on homology groups.

I was trying to prove it in $H_0$ level considering $A-U$ has two connected componenent and $S^2-U$ is connected but not able to conclude anything. Any hints or help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is an equatorial semicircle of $X = S^2$. We have $X/A \approx S^2$, thus
$$H_n(X,A) \approx H_n(S^2,*) =\begin{cases} 0 & n \ne 2 \\ \mathbb Z& n = 2 \end{cases}$$
(note that $(X,A)$ is a cofibred pair and $A$ is contractible).

For $n= 2$ we get the exact sequence
$$H_2(X \setminus U) \to H_2(X  \setminus U, A \setminus U) \to H_1(A \setminus U)$$
Since $X \setminus U$ is contractible and $A \setminus U$ is the disjoint union of two contractible spaces, this reduces to
$$0 \to H_2(X  \setminus U, A \setminus U) \to 0$$
which shows that $H_2(X  \setminus U, A \setminus U) = 0$.